# Webkit animations performance on IPad

Tags: javascript, performance, ipad, mobile-safari

Do webkit based transformations/animations affect JS performance on the IPad?  Is there a separate graphics processor to handle the webkit stuff?

Basically I am developing a program with some simple webkit animations, but a bunch of them, and I think I have to pull out the animations because its making the Ipad slow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may check out *Thomas Fuchs's* article on: **[Making an iPad HTML5 App & making it really fast](http://mir.aculo.us/2010/06/04/making-an-ipad-html5-app-making-it-really-fast/)**

Some of the points he makes are

1. Images slow things down immensely– get rid of them
2. Avoid text-shadow & box-shadow
3. Avoid opacity (interferes with hardware-accelerated rendering)
4. Use translate3d, not translate (the latter is not always hard-accelerated)
5. Make sure to use [non-progressive JPEGs](http://mir.aculo.us/2010/08/12/optimizing-images-for-hardware-acceleration-on-the-iphone-and-ipad/) if you want hardware-acceleration

Comment: i was using opacity, so this definitely helped.  Im trying to get rid of all lag on the IPad.

Comment: The GPU acceleration for 3D rotations in particular on mobile safari can be quirky. Rotation around a single axis - superfast, rotation around 2 axes with nested divs - superslow.