# Workaround for opacity on ipad?

Tags: css, ipad

It's clear that setting opacity to anything but 1 hurts performance on the ipad.

[Webkit animations performance on IPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060183/webkit-animations-performance-on-ipad)

I am working on a feature that would benefit immensely from setting the opacity of some elements to less than 1.

[image: Screenshot of my app]

The problem is that as I scroll down the ipad, any element which has opacity less than 1 isn't displayed. Only when scrolling stops are the elements rendered properly. Can anyone think of a trick to achieve the same affect that I need?

Answer (score 2):

The same thing happens with positioned elements on the iPad. You could probably overlay the thing you are trying to make opaque with a semi-transparent PNG image. It's hard to say how difficult this would be without seeing your markup, but it probably wouldn't be too bad.

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1:
If you are using a solid background you could try overlaying a transparent png.

solution 2:
or you could create  a image sprite png. or even jpg really depends on your background. you would add an overlay say in photoshop instead of actually over it and would be swapping background positions.

solution 3:
having a png with transparency background width 100% height 100%.

```
<div id="bg"></bg> <-- set z-index to 1
<div class="element dead"></div><-- set z-index to 0
<div class="element alive"></div><-- set z-index to 3
```

The dead elements will show up behind the bg looking as if they had faded out.
See this in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/cma9B/2/

Also depending on if you need the user to interact with the elements makes a difference which route you will want to go.

Comment: I like that third approach. I'm unsure whether the iPad will still have problems with thi. Will test and come back and accept if it work out. Thanks!